# Python 2.7 - Help using an API (HL7)

Tags: python, api, hl7

I am new to programming and Python.

I have a very basic python script that connects to server and send a text message:

```
#!/usr/bin/python           
import socket               
s = socket.socket()        
host = '127.0.0.1' 
port = 4106               
s.connect((host, port))
message = 'test1' 
s.send(message)
print s.recv(1024)
s.close
```

Everything is fine, except that this message is an HL7 message and needs to wrapped in MLLP
I found this API that I think can do this for me (http://python-hl7.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#mllp-network-client)

So I modified my program to the following, but I keep getting the error message: NameError: name 'MLLPClient' is not defined

```
#!/usr/bin/python           
import socket   
import hl7                 
host = '127.0.0.1' 
port = 4106               
with MLLPClient(host, port) as client:
  client.send_message('test1')
print s.recv(1024)
s.close
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in different ways;

If you import the top-level package

```
import hl7
```

You should create the object with its complete name:

```
with hl7.client.MLLPClient(host, port) as client:
    client.send_message('test1')
```

or you can import only the specific class:

```
from hl7.client import MLLPClient
```

and use it like you did in your example.

See the [modules documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

maybe `from hl7 import MLLPClient`  ?

or maybe do

```
with hl7.MLLPClient(...) as ...
```

Comment: If you are trying to send an HL7 message to a particular place, how would you find the hostname and port, for example, of a hospital in a specific town?